# JSON data type not validated in spring boot

Tags: json, spring-boot, jackson

I have json like below

```
"name": {
  "title": "Mr",
  "firstName": "somename",
  "middleName": "middleName",
  "lastName": "Micheal",
  "maidenName": "maidenName"
}
```

My POJO class is defined as like below

```
    @JsonInclude(JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL)
@Data
@Validated
public class Name {

    @Length(min = 0,max = 10)
    private String title;

    @Length(min = 0,max = 50)
    private String firstName;

    @Length(min = 0,max = 700)
    private String middleName;

    @Length(min = 0,max = 50)
    private String lastName;

    @Length(min = 0,max = 50)
    private String maidenName;
}
```

Controller class

```
    @RestController
@RequestMapping("/price/v1")
@Validated
public class MyServerController implements PriceAPI {

    @PostMapping(value = "/price",
            produces = {"application/json"},
            consumes = {"application/json"})
    public ResponseEntity<SomeResponse> getmyResponse
           (@Valid
            @RequestBody Name name) {
        return ResponseEntity.ok(myService.getmyResponse(priceData));
    }
}
```

Issue is when I provide integer to my json first name field it is not throwing any error. example

```
"name": {
  "title": "Mr",
  "firstName": 123,
  "middleName": "middleName",
  "lastName": "Micheal",
  "maidenName": "maidenName"
}
```

I tried few options in jackson and explored few Json annotation. But those are not working as expected. Please help me on this.

Comment: Updated my controller class

Comment: `CustomerData` and `Name` are two different classes. Am I missing something?

Comment: @Pijotrek - It is my typo.. updated my controller class with Name

Comment: @User-Upvotedon'tsayThanks - In my case, I am not using objectmapper for request body. I have used class to accept the request body for my REST API.

Comment: 123 is still treated as string , if you do not want firstName field  to be an integer or a number, you can use @Pattern annotations above the firstName field

Comment: @Emmanuel Ogoma - could you please elaborate more on this behaviour.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to include a pattern for the individual field by defining a regular expression with the `@Pattern` annotation. In this case, for the `firstName` field, the appropriate `@Pattern` should be defined as --

```
@Length(min = 0, max = 50)
@Pattern(regexp = "^[A-Za-z]+$")
private String firstName;
```

Include a suitable pattern for all the other fields as required.